# Change the built-in project templates of Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community. Today I updated dotnet from `1.0` to `1.1`. Then I create a new web application to test, everything goes well except that the project template is still using the old versions, like:

```
//global.json
 "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"         //there is a newer version
 }

//project.json
 "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",         //still 1.0.0
      "type": "platform"
    }
 }
```

I can change it manually (in fact I did, it's working fine). I wonder if I can change the built-in template so that everything will be easier next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in this folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\WebTemplates\NetCore\CSharp\1033`

Depending on the project type you are using you could modify the files to suit your needs, however if you change any of these files, those changes could be lost in a future update of Visual Studio or some of its components.

You might be better off creating your own project template and going from there.